# What is the best way to handle an object of objects in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Can Anyone please lead me in the correct way to handle a data structure like this :

```
 {  
      "1":{  
         "id":"1",
         "name":"Facebook",
         "created_at":"",
         "updated_at":"",
         "fields":{  
            "1":{  
               "id":"1",
               "name":"G\u00f6rsel",
               "service_id":"1",
               "ord":"1",
               "token":"fimage",
               "type":"1",
               "created_at":null,
               "updated_at":null
            },
            "2":{  
               "id":"2",
               "name":"Post Metini",
               "service_id":"1",
               "ord":"2",
               "token":"ftext",
               "type":"2",
               "created_at":null,
               "updated_at":null
            },
            "3":{  
               "id":"3",
               "name":"Ba\u015fl\u0131k",
               "service_id":"1",
               "ord":"3",
               "token":"fheader",
               "type":"2",
               "created_at":null,
               "updated_at":null
            },
            "4":{  
               "id":"4",
               "name":"Link A\u00e7\u0131klamas\u0131",
               "service_id":"1",
               "ord":"4",
               "token":"flink_description",
               "type":"2",
               "created_at":null,
               "updated_at":null
            }
         }
      },
      "2":{  },
      "3":{  }
}
```

I noticed that all angular cool functions like sorting, filtering looping through data are based onto javascript arrays so what is the best approach to handle similar structures in Angular 4, for example for use in *ngFor, or using filters and so on.. for example if I try to iterate this object with NgFor I get

> Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of
>   type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

at this point I do not know what action is best, I can ofcurse convert the object to an array, but is that my best approach?

Comment: @Sajeetharan
what is the best approach to handle similar structures in Angular 4 ?
should I convert it  to an array and all inner objects to arrays as well or should I use some custom code to parse my Object? what is the best approach!

Comment: you can handle any structure since its a json

Comment: flagged as unclear what you are asking, best approach related to what use case? You can handle with no problems objects, maps and arrays in javascript. This isnt truly angular related.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Edited

Comment: @Sajeetharan I know, I edited the queston to be clearer

Comment: I would write own pipes to transform my objects into array-like objects.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Finally an answer,
any chance you can provide a little bit detailed answer on how to do that ? a link would be great,  thank you

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/pipes

Comment: You can have array of array and then easily use ngFor to loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the structure could be improved. It is a better option to use an array of objects under "fields". Then you would be able to loop through that array.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may encounter a similar question, 
based on @[ThomasSablik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4645334/thomas-sablik) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791905/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-an-object-of-objects-in-angular-4/46792990#comment80530750_46791905) and after taking his advise about using Pipes to handle it, I could find the suitable approach I was looking for,
and I'm currently using the following pipe which is working like a charm

```
export class KeyValuesPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Thanks to Thomas for putting me on the right direction.